prometheus total node request query
I'm trying to write a query for a nodes total memory request (/allocatable).
I came up with (I intentionally ignore init containers):
    100
  *
    sum by (node) (
        max by (pod, container, namespace, node) (kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="memory"})
      * on (namespace, pod) group_left ()
        max by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase=~"Pending|Running"})
    )
/
  max by (node) (kube_node_status_allocatable{resource="memory"})

This seems fine most of the time, but sometimes I see a bump over 100 I can't explain.
So there's either an issue with the query itself, or the metrics.
Only theory I could come up with is that for some reason, kube-state-metric would continue reporting a pod after it's already deleted/completed, leading to a short while where the total requests are too high. But it seems like an unlikely explanation.
Any ideas?
